# Endomorphisms of the Jacobian of a general Prym curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve of genus $\geq 3$, and $\sigma $ a fixed point free involution of $C$. Assume that  $(C,\sigma )$ is general in the moduli space of such pairs (which is irreducible). I expect that the endomorphism ring of the Jacobian of $C$ is $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\sigma ^*$. Does someone know a proof or a reference?

Comment: It is easy to see that the endomorphism ring is of rank $2$, using the fact that the endomorphism ring of $J(D)$, $D$ being the quotient by the involution, and of the Prym variety are both $\mathbb{Z}$. One could perhaps complete the proof by showing that $\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z} \sigma^*$ is a  saturated subgroup of $\mathrm{End}(H^1(C,\mathbb{Z}))$. (I think an explicit description of $\sigma^*$ is given in the book of Birkanhake and Lange.)

Comment: Very good, thanks! In fact there is a (very natural) basis of $H^1(C,\mathbb{Z})$ such that $\sigma ^*$ exchanges two basis vectors -- this is enough to show that $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\sigma ^*$ is saturated in $\mathrm{End}(H^1(C,\mathbb{Z}))$.